# Is it normal to collect flow in infinite loop?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have function like below, and I need to send request to some API each second.
Is it correct realization?

Data from API wraps into kotlin Flow, and then in this function I collect it.

```kotlin
private fun fetchOrder() {
    serviceScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (isGettingOrders) {
            delay(1000)
            getOrderInfoUseCase(outletId)
                .collect { result ->
                    result.onSuccess {
                        if (currentOrderId != it.orderId) {
                            currentOrderId = it.orderId
                            _order.emit(it)
                        }
                    }
                    result.onFailure {
                        printLog("${it.message}")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid of that this function start infinite Flows

**UPD**

```kotlin
fun getOrderInfoUseCase(outletId: Int): Flow<Result<OrderInfo>> =
    receiptRemoteRepository.getOrderInfo(outletId).map {
        Result.success(it)
    }.catch {
        Result.failure<Throwable>(it)
    }
```

**UPD2:**
I need to send request to remote API each second, so the answer is it correct to do it like in function fetchOrder(), or each second there will append new collector of the flow?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How is `getOrderInfoUseCase` defined?

Comment: You did not answer my first question. What are you trying to do? You're asking "is it the correct realization". Realization of what?

Comment: @marstran, ah, sorry. Updated my question again. :)

Comment: "I need to send request to remote API each second" - do you really though? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to make requests every second sounds very strange. Sounds like sockets would be more applicable.

But assuming we are stuck with this requirement, and assuming the upstream flow is finite, the way you're collecting it looks OK. You are collecting it synchronously within the while loop, so you'll never be collecting more than one at a time from this function. The actual time between requests will be one second plus however long it took to complete the previous request.

However, the upstream flow seems questionable to begin with. It doesn't make sense to use flows that only ever contain one item. Conceptually, that is not a flow. Your single request should just be a suspend function.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know about sockets, but in my project I can't use it, because of hardware restrictions.